# How do I save a Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I created a registration form on a Google Form and emailed it to be filled out. Now I want to save the form and the answers to the questions. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "save"? Also show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

**Google Forms and their submissions are auto-saved on the fly**.

It is always best practice to also link your form to a Google Sheet (where they are auto-saved as well once linked).
This way the submissions can be further manipulated.

[image]